# How to create a weighted sum of some columns in a Polars DataFrame?

Tags: python-polars

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to calculate the weighted sum of a subset of the columns in a Polars DataFrame and add it to the DataFrame as new column. So let's say I want to multiply columns p1-p3 in the DataFrame below by the following weights and then sum them to create a new column.

```py
weights = [7.4, 3.2, -0.13]

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "p1": [44.3, 2.3, 2.4, 6.2],
        "p2": [7.3, 8.4, 10.3, 8.443],
        "p3": [70.3, 80.4, 100.3, 80.443],
        "p4": [16.4, 18.2, 11.5, 18.34],
    }
)
df
```

```
id   p1     p2      p3      p4
i64  f64    f64     f64     f64
1    44.3   7.3     70.3    16.4
2    2.3    8.4     80.4    18.2
3    2.4    10.3    100.3   11.5
4    6.2    8.443   80.443  18.34
```

I have come up with the following solution that calculates the correct answer, but I feel that there is likely a simpler, more idiomatic method that would enable me to select the columns of interest without needing to re-specify the `df` within the `with_columns` function. Any suggestions?

```py
df.with_columns(
    [
        df.select(
            [
                pl.col(col) * pl.lit(weights[i])
                for i, col in enumerate(["p1", "p2", "p3"])
            ]
        )
        .fold(lambda c1, c2: c1 + c2)
        .alias("index"),
    ]
)
```

```
id  p1    p2     p3      p4     index
i64 f64   f64    f64     f64    f64
1   44.3  7.3    70.3    16.4   342.041
2   2.3   8.4    80.4    18.2   33.448
3   2.4   10.3   100.3   11.5   37.681
4   6.2   8.443  80.443  18.34  62.44
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick that may also help: commonly used folds are built into the `sum`, `max`, `min`, `all`, and `any` functions - when called with a **list of expressions**.

For example:

```py
pl.sum([exp1, exp2, etc...])
```

is syntactic sugar for the commonly used addition fold:

```py
pl.fold(pl.lit(0), f=lambda c1, c2: c1 + c2, exprs =[expr1, expr2, etc...])
```

Thus, we can do the following:

```py
col_names = ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
weights = [7.4, 3.2, -0.13]
df.with_column(
    pl.sum(
        [pl.col(col_nm) * wgt
         for col_nm, wgt in zip(col_names, weights)]
    ).alias("index")
)
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ p1   ┆ p2    ┆ p3     ┆ p4    ┆ index   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64    ┆ f64   ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 44.3 ┆ 7.3   ┆ 70.3   ┆ 16.4  ┆ 342.041 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2.3  ┆ 8.4   ┆ 80.4   ┆ 18.2  ┆ 33.448  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2.4  ┆ 10.3  ┆ 100.3  ┆ 11.5  ┆ 37.681  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 6.2  ┆ 8.443 ┆ 80.443 ┆ 18.34 ┆ 62.44   │
└─────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

I used `zip` instead of `enumerate` .. but that's a stylistic choice.  And I allowed Polars to broadcast the weight scalar to a literal, instead of explictly using `pl.lit`.

Another trick that may help with readability: we can generate the list of expressions outside the with_column/with_columns/select contexts.

For example:

```py
col_names = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]
weights = [7.4, 3.2, -0.13, 0.0]
wghtd_cols = [
    pl.col(col_nm) * wgt
    for col_nm, wgt in zip(col_names, weights)
    if wgt != 0.0
]

df.with_column(pl.sum(wghtd_cols).alias("index"))
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ p1   ┆ p2    ┆ p3     ┆ p4    ┆ index   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64    ┆ f64   ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 44.3 ┆ 7.3   ┆ 70.3   ┆ 16.4  ┆ 342.041 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2.3  ┆ 8.4   ┆ 80.4   ┆ 18.2  ┆ 33.448  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2.4  ┆ 10.3  ┆ 100.3  ┆ 11.5  ┆ 37.681  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 6.2  ┆ 8.443 ┆ 80.443 ┆ 18.34 ┆ 62.44   │
└─────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

This is particularly useful when one part of your code is generating the weights and/or selecting columns, and another part of your code is creating the resulting weighted sum column in the DataFrame.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for taking this to the next level and providing alternative formulations.

Comment: It seems the column is not added "in-place", the result must be assigned back to `df`: `df = df.with_column...`

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You can use the `pl.fold` expression directly.

```py
df.with_columns([
    pl.fold(acc=0, f=lambda c1, c2: c1 + c2, exprs=[
        pl.col(col) * pl.lit(weights[i])
        for i, col in enumerate(["p1", "p2", "p3"])
    ]).alias("index")
])
```

```
shape: (4, 6)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ id  ┆ p1   ┆ p2    ┆ p3     ┆ p4    ┆ index   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64   ┆ f64    ┆ f64   ┆ f64     │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 44.3 ┆ 7.3   ┆ 70.3   ┆ 16.4  ┆ 342.041 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2.3  ┆ 8.4   ┆ 80.4   ┆ 18.2  ┆ 33.448  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2.4  ┆ 10.3  ┆ 100.3  ┆ 11.5  ┆ 37.681  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 6.2  ┆ 8.443 ┆ 80.443 ┆ 18.34 ┆ 62.44   │
└─────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Yes that is where I was thinking I should be able to get to. Thanks,